Stuck with bunch of failed on screen when turning on
After cancelling ubuntu update my laptop stuck like this:1
Update from GUI but i forget the version because I rarely use the laptop. So when I use it there's update notification and I just pressed it, but i don't know that this need a long time and I in a hurry that time so i just cancelled it

Which version of Ubuntu/other Linux were you upgrading from and to? How did you start the upgrade, by GUI or terminal? What made you cancel the upgrade? Edit your question and add these and other information we ask for in comments.
